# Swift_Message::__toString() must not throw an exception

Tags: email, laravel, mailgun

Hello i am using mailgun t send an email, it worked before but i added some new parameters and changed stuff in the view now when i try to send an email this error is returned:

```
FatalErrorException in MailgunTransport.php line 0: Method Swift_Message::__toString() must not throw an exception
```

This is my mail function:

```
$cart = Cart::where('cart_key', $cart_key)
            ->get()

$parameters = array(
    'ticket_code' => $reference_code,
    'date_of_purchase' => date('l, d m Y H:i A'),
    'cart' => $cart,
    'amount' => $amount,
    'service_charge' => $percentage_charge,
    'loyalty_discount' => $loyalty_discount,
    'customer' => Session::get('customer') // this is an array
);

// Sending Mail
Mail::queue('emails.purchase', $parameters, function ($message) use ($customer_email) {
    if ($message->to($customer_email, '')->subject('Ticket Purchase'))
    {
        $all_good = true;
    }
});
```

this is my view:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        ...
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <img src="{{ $message->embed('/images/logo.png') }}" alt="" title="" class="logo"/>
        </div>
        <p>You successfully made a purchase on: {{ $date_of_purchase }}</p>
        <p>Use the following ticket code to track your transaction: <b>{{ $ticket_code }}</b></p>

        <table class="table summary">
            @if ($customer)
            <tr>
                <td width="130"><h5>Name:</h5></td>
                <td><h5>{{ $customer['fullname'] }}</h5></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="130" width="100"><h5>Telephone No.:</h5></td>
                <td><h5>{{ $customer['telephone'] }}</h5></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td width="130"><h5>Email Address:</h5></td>
                <td><h5>{{ $customer['email'] }}</h5></td>
            </tr>
            @endif
            <tr>
                <td><h5></h5></td>
                <td><h5></h5></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table class="table summary">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align:center;" >Description</th>
                <th style="text-align:center;" width="30">No.</th>
                <th style="text-align:center;" width="100">Price (GHS)</th>
                <th style="text-align:center;" width="120">Amount (GHS)</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @foreach ($cart as $item)
                @if ($item['item_type'] != 'extra')
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:center;" ><b>{{ $item['item_desc']  }}</b></td>
                    <td style="text-align:center;" ><b>{{ $item['item_no'] }}</b></td>
                    <td style="text-align:center;" ><b>{{ '₵ ' . $item['item_price'] }}</b></td>
                    <td style="text-align:center;" ><b>{{ '₵ ' . ($item['item_price'] * $item['item_no'])  }}</b></td>
                </tr>
                @endif
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:center;" colspan="4"><h5>Extras</h5></td>
                </tr>
                @if ($item['item_type'] == 'extra')
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:center;" ><b>{{ $item['item_desc']  }}</b></td>
                    <td style="text-align:center;" ><b> - </b></td>
                    <td style="text-align:center;" ><b>{{ '₵ ' . $item['item_price'] }}</b></td>
                    <td style="text-align:center;" ><b>{{ '₵ ' . $item['item_price'] }}</b></td>
                </tr>
                @endif
            @endforeach
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:center;" ><b>Service Charge</b></td>
                    <td style="text-align:center;" ><b> - </b></td>
                    <td style="text-align:center;" ><b>{{ '₵ ' . $service_charge }}</b></td>
                    <td style="text-align:center;" ><b>{{ '₵ ' . $service_charge }}</b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:center;" ><b>Loyalty Discount</b></td>
                    <td style="text-align:center;" ><b> - </b></td>
                    <td style="text-align:center;" ><b>{{ '- ₵ ' . $loyalty_discount }}</b></td>
                    <td style="text-align:center;" ><b>{{ '- ₵ ' . $loyalty_discount }}</b></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="3">&nbsp;</th>
                <th colspan="1">Total: {{ '₵ ' . $amount }}</th>
            </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please note that this is just a section of my entire code, all variables have indeed been set.

I have had never had this issue before and i'm glad i had it now coz now if i can find a solution i won't be bothered by it again. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by something in your view potentially throwing an exception.

I'd take a guess and say thats your `$customer['fullname']` and such, you should check they're set first.

Comment: Hmm i just checked all the data, for some reason it worked when i took out "{{ $message->embed('/images/logo.png') }}".